# Summarize results within a C# foreach

Tags: c#

I have an object that traverses a list using `foreach` and returns the value of the object I'm accessing.

Depending on the case, the object returns a `count = 10`, for example.

I need to summarize the values ​​of all these records and I'm trying as follows, but it returns nothing.

If I remove the `+=` and leave only `=`, I only retrieve the first record.

How can I summarize all the records?

```
public decimal? ValesDisponiveis
{
    get
    {
        decimal? informacaoRetorno = null;

        if (ValeCreditos != null)
        {
            foreach (ValeCredito vale in ValeCreditos)
            {
                informacaoRetorno += vale.ValesDisponiveis;
            }
        }
        return informacaoRetorno;
    }
}
```

Comment: it depends on the ValeCreditos, check it to have more than one record

Comment: Good time to start the debugging-feature. Set a breakpoint into the loop and check if it gets hit.

Comment: decimal? informacaoRetorno = 0

Comment: `1 + null == null`.

Comment: Did I put decimal? Returninformation = 0; and it worked, I didn't realize it, thank you very much!

Comment: `return ValeCreditos?.Sum(x => x.ValesDisponiveis)`...

Comment: As a matter of design, you may want to consider ensuring `ValeCreditos` is never `null` -- that is, always have a valid container, even if it's empty. This saves out on a lot of `null` checks. If you must have different behavior, consider making the distinction at the top level, once, rather than in every method/property individually (the null object pattern).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is:

```
decimal? informacaoRetorno = null;
```

Instead use:

```
decimal? informacaoRetorno = 0;
```

Or in this case better without nullable because initialization with 0:

```
decimal informacaoRetorno = 0;
```

**Edit**

As mentioned in the comments if you still want `null` as a valid result if the `IEnumerable` is null you still can do the following:

```
if (ValeCreditos == null)
        return null;
    
return ValeCreditors.Sum(x => x.ValesDisponiveis);
```

If `ValesDisponiveis` has already the correct base type.

Comment: @imsmn of course not, copy pasted and forgot to replace the null with 0 and also was to weak for a R press. Thanks :)

Comment: `decimal? informacaoRetorno = null;` can well be *correct*: we may want to return `null`  (which stands for *unknown*, *incomputable* etc.) if  `ValeCreditos` is `null` or empty

Comment: @DmitryBychenko depends on the context but of course `null` could also be a valid value. I prefer in such cases often to still retun `0` but as mentioned depends on the context / rest of the code. My answer was just for the part why the result was `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to return `null` in case there's *no items* to be summed (say, when `ValeCreditos` is *empty*) you should check for `HasValue`:

```
public decimal? ValesDisponiveis
{
    get
    {
        decimal? informacaoRetorno = null;

        if (ValeCreditos != null)
        {
            foreach (ValeCredito vale in ValeCreditos)
            {
                if (informacaoRetorno.HasValue) // business as usual: just add
                    informacaoRetorno += vale.ValesDisponiveis;
                else // null + value == null, that's why we assign
                    informacaoRetorno = vale.ValesDisponiveis;
            }
        }
        return informacaoRetorno;
    }
}
```

This code returns `null` on `null` or empty `ValeCreditos` and sum of items otherwise.

Comment: You wrote twice `informacaoRetorno += vale.ValesDisponiveis;` which will again result in the error (copy paste i guess).

Comment: @MrBlank: Thank you! Copy + Paste is *evil*

Comment: Yes, i also had a Copy + Paste mistake in my answer :)